# originalEvent.touches for iPad is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

Been searching everywhere to find how to make this touches on the "sliderBar" work on iPad. I pretty much use this http://www.the-xavi.com/articles/trouble-with-touch-events-jquery & blend in with my `mouseDown` function :

```
function handleSliderSlide(event, ui) {
    if(event.originalEvent.touches && event.originalEvent.touches.length) {
        event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    } else if (event.originalEvent.changedTouches && event.originalEvent.changedTouches.length) {
        event = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
    }

    if(event.originalEvent.type === 'keydown') {
        var maxScroll = $('#yearsWrapper').attr('scrollWidth') - $('#yearsWrapper').width();
        var years = $('#dates li').length - 1;
        $('#sliderBar').slider('option', 'step', years);
        $('#yearsWrapper').attr({
            scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100)
        });
    } else {
        var maxScroll = $('#yearsWrapper').attr('scrollWidth') - $('#yearsWrapper').width();
        $('#sliderBar').slider('option', 'step', 1);
        $('#yearsWrapper').attr({
            scrollLeft: ui.value * (maxScroll / 100)
        });
    }
}
```

The HTML code pretty much like this:

```
<div id="timeline">
    <div id="dates">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#year1">1900</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#year2">2000</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="sliderBarWrapper">
            <div id="sliderBar" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <a href="#" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="left: 34%;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="yearsWrapper">
        <div id="years">
            <div class="shadow">
                <div id="year1">
                    <a href="#">slider 1900</a>
                    <p>Year 1900 info</p>
                </div>
                <div id="year2">
                    <a href="#">slider 2000</a>
                    <p>Year 2000 info</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End years -->
    </div>
    <!-- End yearsWrapper -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is the following:

You first overwrite `event` with the first touch object:

```
event = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
```

Then (I think) you treat your `event` object as if it is still was the original object:

```
if(event.originalEvent.type === 'keydown') ...
```

So essentially you are trying to access `event.originalEvent.touches[0].originalEvent.type`, which as far as I know should not point at anything ([have a look at the Touch Events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-touch-events-20110505/#attributes) which describes the touch object and its attributes in detail).

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: wow sorry i didn't know i got a reply in my Q. Actually it was missing a jQuery library .js file, once I insert it and it was working right away. but THANK YOU much for the answer!